Trying to connect Power Automate to Amazon Web Service is returning this error "Details: Server HMAC algorithm not found "
I have this SFTP-SSH action inside Power Automate, where I am trying to connect to Amazon Web Service using those details: -

Private key using RSA
FingerPrint
USerName
EndPoint URL

As follow:-

But I am getting this error:-
Test connection failed. Details: Server HMAC algorithm not found clientRequestId: 52fa5e6c-abcf-11a1-334f-a34b57b7d6b5

Now I am confused on what is causing this error? is it an issue inside Power Automate or inside AWS? and how this can be fixed? or we can not connect Power Automate to AWS?
Thanks
